# SAP UI5/Fiori Check active session of the same web application in another tab

Tags: session, sapui5, session-cookies, sap-fiori

I am working on a Sap Fiori app in Neo environment for filling out a questionnaire.
The problem is if the user opens 2 tabs of the same app, the answers are stored in the questionnaire database incorrectly, as well as the calculation of the final result.
What I would like is if a user opens the same page in another tab of the same browser (or even on another browser, if possible) to check if there is already an active session and to interrupt the execution of the new session.

Considering that the app also calls a nodejs service deployed on Cloud Foundry and that the opening of this web app, deployed on SAP BTP, is done from SuccessFactors:
-**is there a way to be able to control the opening of a new session in javascript**? (solution I would prefer)
-if not what is the alternative?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

I have tried to check cookies, the URLs of other open tabs, try to check the history but without any concrete result and they still do not seem like good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution which works cross-browser will rely on something implemented on the back end for this locking system. You would need to check the back end at the beginning and end of the questionnaire to behave accordingly.

If this is not an option I suggest using the local storage of the browser as this locking repository. You can give your browser window a random name and store some metadata together with it. In this scenario, opening the app in other browser or in a private tab would bypass the lock.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/util/Storage",
    "sap/m/MessageBox"
], (Controller, Storage, MessageBox) => {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("yourapp.controller.App", {

        onInit: function() {

            // Give the current tab a random name
            window.name = +((Math.random() * 10).toFixed(2))

            // Initialize local storage with app namesapce
            var oMyStorage = new Storage(Storage.Type.local, "app");

            // Read current local storage 
            var sCurrentData = oMyStorage.get("activeTab") || "{}";
            var oCurrentData = JSON.parse(sCurrentData)

            // Other validations can be done like checking how recent the other window was opened or
            // add an option to unlock/refresh the local storage
            if (sCurrentData && window.name != oCurrentData.activeTab) {
                MessageBox.error(`There is an active tab opened at ${oCurrentData.openedAt}`)
                return;
            }

            // in case no data is found, add data on local storage
            var oStorageData = {
                activeTab: window.name,
                openedAt: new Date()
            }
            oMyStorage.put("activeTab", JSON.stringify(oStorageData));


        },

    });

});
```